# Server Redirects vs Sitecore Internal Redirects

Tags: content-editor

Recently my company changed names. A server side script was created to change any URL's from `www.name.org` to `https://name.org`.

I am now tasked with fixing hundreds of 404 and 302 redirects. All of my internal redirects that I have created inside Sitecore under the Redirects tab are not working.

Is it possible that server level script prevents the reading on the redirect set up inside Sitecore?

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! What _Redirects_ tab are you referring to? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: There is no redirect functionality in Sitecore other than aliases. So you must be using one of the redirect modules. Which one would help with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue. Sorry @chrisauer I couldnt describe which Redirect module that was currently installed, I just came on board a little while ago and was not given any real documentation on how or company's site was built.

Really appreciate your responses to my question. Turns out these redirect are going to have to be set on the server

Comment: Hi @Terri Hall, just to answer your specific question, yes any server side specific 301 redirects that are configured in IIS, will not be editable in Sitecore.  OOTB with Sitecore, there isn't a mechanism to manage redirects, unless there has been something custom built.  But anything in IIS that's been configured for the website, would take precedents over the custom logic happening on the application end.